# Why can't one implement a C# interface's method with a more general argument's type than the one specified in the interface

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Let's say we have an interface derived from other two general interfaces

```cs
public interface ISpecificInterface : IGeneralInterfaceA, IGeneralInterfaceB
```

And we have another interface declaring a method that accepts the aforementioned interface as a parameter type

```cs
public interface ISimpleVisitor
{
    void Visit(ISpecificInterface object)
}
```

What I'd like to have is an ability to implement that interface's method using one of the `ISpecificInterface`'s ancestors as an argument's type. So the implementation would only be aware of methods declared in a specific ancestor and not all of them.

```cs
public class SimpleVisitor : ISimpleVisitor
{
    public void Visit(IGeneralInterfaceA object)
    {
        object.GeneralInterfaceAMethod();
        object.GeneralInterfaceBMethod(); // This method would not be visible here
    }
}
```

Intellisense tells me that it's apparently not possible.

While I can accept that it is just the way it is, I was wondering what's the point of that restriction if we're moving up the inheritance tree and can be sure that the argument implementing `ISpecificInterface` definitely implements `IGeneralInterfaceA`?

**UPD:**

Perhaps I did not express my intentions clear enough. My idea is not about forcing a user to guess what type he can provide there, but much rather about limiting an implementation to only see a portion of the object it got provided. The user would still have to provide instance in accordance to the interface contract.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. ISimpleVisitor.Visit contract says that Visit accept ISpecificInterface as parameter. End of story.

Comment: clients of your base-interface would still only see the most basic signature which asks for `IGeneralInterface`. So they could still provide some completely different instance implementing the base-interface as well.

Comment: Seems your inheritance is broken. Why would you want to **hide** information about an object? Either `ISpecificInterface` **inherits** `IGeneralInterfaceB` or it doesn´t. You can´t implement the interface but hide the fact that you do so.

Comment: If you want to know why the language was designed the way that it was then *ask the people that designed the language*.  Random people on the internet can't tell you why Microsoft decided to design the language the way that they did.

Comment: Your interface says that `Visit` accepts a parameter of type `ISpecificInterface`. That means it can use any of `ISpecificInterface`'s methods, including the ones not implemented in `IGeneralInterfaceA`. If you want `Visit` to work with `IGeneralInterfaceA` objects, you must specify that in the interface, and then the compiler would disallow references to `GeneralInterfaceBMethod` as illegal.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine it was possible to implement an interface-method with a more **derived** type. What´s the purpose of being able to do that? If you have a client of your base-interface he/she has no clue about your `ISpecificInterface` at all:

```
ISimpleVisitor visitor = GetVisitor();
visitor.Visit(new AnotherClass());
```

As `visitor` is of type `ISimpleVisitor` we have no idea about the fact that the actual implementation expects an `ISpecificInterface`. The interface is a **contract**, there´s no reason to make **assumptions**. When an interface defines a method acepting an `IGeneralInterface`, you should be able to provide **any** type of `IGeneralInterface`, not only some **specific** one. Otherwise the purpose of an interface - which is to **de**-couple, was somehow contradicted.

So you see even if we **were** able to implement an interface-member by a more derived type, there´s absolutely no **use** for that.

EDIT: Now let´s assume we can implement an interface-method with a more **abstract** type:

```
ISimpleVisitor visitor = GetVisitor();
visitor.Visit(new AnotherClass());
```

Now the `ISimpleVisitor`-interface expects us to provide an instance of `ISpecificInterface`. So a client has no idea that he/she can actually also provide something more abstract. But even if he **could** know that, we had a problem, as we´re actually tied to `SimpleVisitor`.

```
ISimpleVisitor visitor = GetVisitor();
visitor.Visit(new MyGeneralVisitor());
```

While this may work for a while, it will break as soon as `GetVisitor` returns some other instance of the interface.

Comment: "So you see even if we were able to implement an interface-member by a more derived type, there´s absolutely no use for that."

If you take a look at my question again, you will see that I was asking the opposite: why aren't we able to implement an interface's method with a parameter of a more abstract type, that is higher in the inheritance tree than the one declared in the interface.

Comment: @YanSidorov I think that's just a typo. HimBromBeere meant "by a more abstract type".

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it isn't.
@HimBromBeere 's entire answer seems to be the opposite of what I was asking.

The point of my example is that the **interface declares more specific type than the one we're trying to use in implementation**

Comment: @YanSidorov You´re right, my intent was the other way round. However it makes no sense either way. How would you provide an instance of the more abstract interface to the method, if you don´t know that you *can*?

Comment: @HimBromBeere The point is not about providing an instance of a more abstract type. You can only provide an instance that implements the interface from the contract and, therefore, implements the more abstract interface as well. So why not allow a specific implementation to take only that abstraction into account **if any instance provided by default implements that abstraction**? My intention is not not in forcing a user to guess what type he has to provide, but to **limit the implementation to see only a portion of the object it got provided**.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicetly implement the interface while providing the more general method also:

```
public class SimpleVisitor : ISimpleVisitor
{
    void ISimpleVisitor.Visit(ISpecificInterface object) => this.Visit((IGeneralInterface)object);
    public void Visit(IGeneralInterfaceA object)
    {
        object.GeneralInterfaceAMethod();
        object.GeneralInterfaceBMethod(); // This method would not be visible here
    }
}
```

This enables clients to provide any instance of `ISpecificInterface`, while your code only cares for the general base-interface.